# 11 digit ternary possibilities

Tags: combinatorics

How many $11$ digit ternary strings are there where a $2$ cannot directly follow $1$?

My thinking is:

The total amount of $11$ digit ternary strings $= 3^{11}$

As long as the string contain the combination $1, 2$, the number is not allowed.  There are 10 possibilities of this happening, where the combination can happen in any of the first 10 digits.

Therefore the total number of strings where a $2$ cannot directly follow $1 = 3^{11} - 10$.

However I don't think this captures every possible disallowed string.  For example there is the string $12121212121$, or $12120000000$, and so on.  How can I approach this question, and questions like these in general?  I am new to combinatorics as I just started taking this course.

Thanks!

Comment: A recurrence relation $P(n+1)=2P(n)+\chi(n)$, where $\chi(n)=P(n-1)+\chi(n-1)$.

Comment: @AlapanDas can you please explain?  I just started the course last week so I don't really understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A recurrence relation $P(n+1)=2P(n)+\chi(n)$, where $\chi(n)=P(n-1)+\chi(n-1)$. Which transforms to

$$P(n+1)=1+P(n)+\sum_{k=1}^{n} P(k)$$

This comes as follows.

Suppose there are $n$ digits already. We want to add one more.
We can do in $P(n+1)$ ways.

Now, if the the last/new digit is $0$ or $1$ we don't have to worry about anything. So, we just put those at the last and perform all arrangements for the previous $n$ digits. So, total $2P(n)$ ways.

Now, if the last/new digit is $2$ then we have to worry (we can have total $\chi(n)$ arrangements for this case). Before the $2$ we can end with either $0$ or $2$. For $0$ we can arrange previous $n-1$ digits in $P(n-1)$ ways. For $2$ we can arrange previous $n-1$ digits in $\chi(n-1)$ ways

So, $\chi(n)=P(n-1)+\chi(n-1)$

So, after all we get $P(n+1)=2P(n)+\chi(n)$. where $\chi(n)=P(n-1)+\chi(n-1)$.